# How do you sort a bar chart using sort order from another column?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a column clustered chart which is based on a query that returns 3 columns. These are Rating, SortOrder and Value. My chart uses Rating as Category and Value on the Y axis. However I want to sort the category based on the SortOrder column. So it should have Cash, AA+, AA etc.
Currently Access is sorting in alphabetical order.

[image: Resultset showing desired sort order]

[image: Chart short alphabetical sort order]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate fields so SrtOrdr value is a prefix to Rating value. Since "Not Rated" has 5 digits, the prefix must have 5 characters with filler zeros.

`Format(SrtOdr, "00000 : ") & Rating`

Use that calculated field for the X-axis.

Comment: Wouldn't that give me 00001 Cash as the Rating though?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the prefix must be part of the axis data. Axis data controls sort order. I can only use old MS Graph, not Modern Charts. I don't know if Modern Charts have any way to sort by a field other than chart data field.